# Slow performance of Perl script using nested for loops

Tags: performance, perl, for-loop, nested-loops, bioinformatics

I have a large FASTA file (a genetic sequence, an entire chromosome), where each line contains 50 characters (bases a,g,t, and c). There are about 4 million lines in this file.

I want to reorganize the file so that each character of a line is placed in its own line of a new file.  That is, turn each 50-character line in the original file into 50, single-character lines.  This will result in the entire sequence rewritten as a single column. Ultimately, I want the sequence as a single column so I can then place an adjacent column containing the genomic coordinate position for each base.

This is how I am doing it, using perl and creating a set of `for` loops.

```
unless(@ARGV) {
    # $0 name of the program being executed;
    print "\n usage: $0 filename\n\n"; 
    exit;
}

# use shift to pull off @ARGV value and return to $list;
my $fastafile = shift; 
open(FASTA, "<$fastafile");
my @count =(<FASTA>);
close FASTA;

# print scalar @count;

for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar @count ; $i ++ ) {

#print "$count[$i]\n\n\n\n"; 
my @seq  = split( "", $count[ $i ] ); 
print " line = $i ";
for ( my $j = 0; $j < scalar @seq; $j++ ){
    #my $count =
    print "$seq[$j]  for count = $j \n"; 

    }

}
```

It seems to be working, but it is being slow, very slow.  I am wondering if it is slow because the FASTA file has 4 million lines, or it is slow because of my code, or both.  I am looking for advice to speed up this process.  Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing with the fasta >header?

Comment: Prior to the `for` loops, the header will be ignored.

Comment: Can you explain why are you trying to do this? This seems to me like one of those problems that you're trying to solve the wrong way, kinda of like your problem is how to open the door, the answer is use the key, but you're asking how to bomb doors from a safe distance.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I misunderstood, but is the output goal actually "one character per line" or "a long string containing that character plus a counter per line" ?

Comment: @carandraug, what I want in the end is a two-column file, where the first column is the base and the second column is its genome coordinate or base position. The sequence is from the UCSC genome browser.

Comment: @BRPocock, the immediate goal of the script above is "one character per line."  Ultimately (to do later) is to simply add the second column on by adjusting the script.

Comment: @ES55 but why do you want that? And where in that problem do you fit the split into multiples files with 50 characters? Since the sequence in the original file is in order, if you were to save the files with an order number, you can easily calculate the base number (50*(number of the file -1) + line_number). Still, this looks a very weird problem, so please explain the real problem you're trying to solve, not this tiny detail.

Comment: @carandraug, What I want is a single file (not multiple files) that contains two columns: one for the sequence and the other for the genomic coordinate for the corresponding base in the same row.  The purpose is to use the file to retrieve sequences of genetic elements, the coordinates of which I find in other files that contain genomic annotation information (where specific genes are in terms of coordinates). What would you suggest?

Comment: All, I have tried most of the suggestions below, and they seem to be more or less just as fast (or slow).  I take that to mean that it is the volume of data, rather than the scripting technique, that creates the slowness.

Comment: The main problem is that you are loading the whole file at once.

Comment: Loading the whole file into an array (which I've learned some call slurping) takes only about six seconds.  Turing the lines into a single column takes much, much longer.  Slurping is not the issue I have found. Rather, the speed of the process is slow due to the volume of the data to rearrange. I did initially think that the slowness was actually due to the style of script, but this turned out not to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV or die "\n usage: $0 filename\n\n";

my $line = 0;
while (<>) {
    next if /^>/;
    chomp;

    print 'Line = ', $line++, "\n";
    my $count = 0;
    print "$_ for count = ", $count++, "\n" for split '';
    print "\n";
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl fastaIn`

The above also skips the fasta headers.

Sample output:

```
Line = 0
T for count = 0
A for count = 1
C for count = 2
G for count = 3
A for count = 4
G for count = 5
...
```

Comment: can you describe what the syntax means?  `print "$_ for count = " . $count++, "\n" for split //;`  It looks very streamlined. What does the `for split //` mean/do?

Comment: @ES55 - No arrays are necessary to do the processing you want.  The line in question first `split`s the sequence into its characters, iterating through each using a `for` loop--which assigns each character to `$_`.  `$count` is incremented through each pass of the loop.  The result is a `T for count = 0` like you see above.

Comment: @ES55 - I've changed the `split //` to `split ''`, as you had it.  The have the same effect.

Comment: thanks @Kenosis, I like your style (as always). Still, the flow of the process is slow, but I think that is because the FASTA file is just so large.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are *slurping* the file. While the huge file is being *slurped*, the process will wait until all the I/O is over to start processing. An option is to process the file line by line:

```
open my $fh, '<', $fastafile or die "Error opening file: $!";

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;    # Remove the newline from the end of each line

    my @seq = split //, $line;

    # Loop from 0 to the last index of @seq
    for my $i ( 0 .. $#seq ) {
        print "$seq[$i] for count = $i\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you annotate `( 0 .. $#seq )`...what does that say? Or is the `#` a typo?

Comment: About slurping, the processing begins after about 6 seconds, so the time spent slurping is not short compared to the time it takes to print the output to the screen, which is taking a very long time. I am waiting over 30 min so far.  And the terminal window pauses (pin wheel of death spins) every minute or so, as my computer's fan spins.  The computer is getting hot.

Comment: I see. I have commented the range part. I cannot be sure if my code will work faster in that case or not as I do not have access to the file. Can you give it a try?

Comment: $#var is Perl-ese for "the number of elements which are in the array @var"

Comment: @AlanHaggaiAlavi there is a bug in your code. the count is resetting back to 0 for each line when I think the OP wants to keep the count increasing (so the offsets are correct) you probably want to keep a separate counter and print that

Comment: @BRPocock `$#var` is the syntax for getting the index of the last item in `@var`. To get the *number* of items in an array you would use `scalar(@var)` ( you can omit the `scalar` if it is already in scalar context ).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Bio::SeqIO](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio%3a%3aSeqIO) class to handle this which allows to set `width` and `block` for fasta format (the format specific is handled by [Bio::SeqIO::fasta](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio%3a%3aSeqIO%3a%3afasta)). If I remember correctly, it has some tricks to handle very large sequences though I think these are limited to the writing part (shameful self-advertisement, I implemented one of them last year). Something like this should work fine:

```
use Bio::SeqIO;

## omit the -format option and it will try to guess the format
my $in  = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => $fastafile, -format => 'Fasta');

while (my $seq = $in->next_seq()) {
  my $out = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => ">outputfilename", -format => 'Fasta');
  $out->width(1); # 1 base pair per line
  $out->write_seq($seq);
}
```

Note how this will allow for multiple fasta sequences in the same file (experiment with a fasta file with 6 sequences with a couple of lines to have a feeling for it).

Also, this actually writes a *real* fasta file, so you won't be able to change the code in order to write your 2 column file. But the problem you mention, to have the second column with the base index, does not make a lot of sense to me. If you know the offset for the first base, the second column is just the $column_number + $offset + 1 (to account  for the fasta header). But BioPerl has methods to do this, please don't reinvent the wheel. Load the sequence as a [`Bio::Seq`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio%3a%3aSeq) object, and use its methods to get a subsequence.

```
my $in  = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => $fastafile);

while (my $seq = $in->next_seq()) {
  ## $subseq will be a string with the sequence from bp 500 to 1000
  my $subseq = $seq->subseq(500, 1000);
}
```

I'm unsure how much performance improvement you'll have with this, but anything you think you can improve, please share it back to the BioPerl project.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your main limitation is that you're printing out orders-of-magnitude more data than you're reading in.

If each line is 50 characters + newline, you "should" be writing 100/51 (about twice) as much data.

But printing that long string `"X for count = 29\n"` means you're writing out 15-16 characters per input character...

In addition to which, you're going to eat up a lot of RAM, but 4M lines x 50 chars isn't really "much" these days. Still, that's 20M + housekeeping overhead that you don't need to "spend" here.

Perhaps this is a place where writing your own loops is not as good as using the builtins in Perl's operators like `qq` aka `""` ...

I've also move the variable construction outside the loop, to shave a bit more time off of constructing and garbage-collecting them.

```
 {                            # Inner scope for local $" and my vars            #"
     local $" = "\n";         # Separator character for stringifying lists      #"
     my ($line, @line);       # Avoid cons/gc during the loop
     while ($line = <$fh>)
     {
           chomp $line;       # Strip any newline
           @line = split ('', $line);
           print "@line\n";   # Stringification using $"
     }
 }
```

(sorry, Stack Exchange's syntax highlighting doesn't know $" is a variable name, so the syntax-highlighting is a little weird.)